# Installing the Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-7.1

I want to implement login using facebook in my windows phone 7.1 application

When I try to install **Facebook C# SDK** using the nuget package manager console. It is  added successfully, but when I try to add the reference to my project its giving following error.

[image]

I did not write any code or anything. I just want to add the reference to facebook like `using facebook;` in my code behind file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this and I cannot reproduce the error.

Make sure you uninstall any old version of the SDK.

Then, right-click the project and add the SDK using nuget.

Do not install by hand.

Comment: im installing using nuget only by running `Install-Package Facebook` command in package manager console

Comment: Try right-clicking the project and selecting "Manage NuGet packages" and then selecting the Facebook C# SDK

Answer (score 0):

That error message seems pretty clear - your project is set to target Windows Phone 7.1, but that version of the Facebook SDK doesn't support Windows Phone 7.1

See if there's an updated version of the SDK which supports 7.1, or target your project at a version that the Facebook SDK does support